# How can I select a nested element inside the first child element of a container?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="Container">
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="/img/car1.png" class="Dealer"/>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="/img/car2.png" class="Dealer"/>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="/img/car3.png" class="Dealer"/>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to add `padding-left: 0px` to the first `img`. I have no idea how this would be done. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a specific CSS selector which will only select the first `img`, which is what you're looking for.

```
.Container > div:first-child > div > img.Dealer {
    padding-left:0px;
}
```

And here is a **live demo** of the CSS in action, as applied to your HTML:

```css
.Dealer {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.Container > div:first-child > div > img.Dealer {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/I9ldaCx.png" class="Dealer"/>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/I9ldaCx.png" class="Dealer"/>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/I9ldaCx.png" class="Dealer"/>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/r8hpnbwg/

Comment: ``.Container > div:first-child .Dealer`` works.

Comment: @Jeff For me that does not work: https://jsfiddle.net/r8hpnbwg/1/

Comment: Sorry, no need for the last ``>`` child selector. https://jsfiddle.net/jeffreyTang/r8hpnbwg/3/

Comment: @Jeff I feel it's kind of subjective at that point -  it depends on whether OP needs the extra specificity or not going forwards.

Comment: maybe, I feel like it's best to make the styles as simple as possible at first then only override with specificity when needed. Believe me I've been on projects where authors were too specific up front and it made altering styles a major pain.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to add `padding-left: 0px` to the first img. I have no idea
>   how this would be done.

If this `padding` is unique to this image, and you want to keep things simple, you can simply use an `id`.

HTML

```
<img src="/img/car1.png" class="Dealer" id="unique-style" />
```

CSS

```
#unique-style { padding-left: 0px; }
```

---

Or (as noted by @Jeff in the comments) you can use another `class`:

```
<img src="/img/car1.png" class="Dealer unique-style" />
```

CSS

```
.unique-style { padding-left: 0px; }
```

Comment: A nice suggestion, but there is a simple pure css solution.

Comment: @Jeff, agreed. Various other answers, including yours, already cover that. Since the OP said *I have no idea how...*, I thought I would offer a different perspective, which still adheres to best practices.

Comment: fair enough. If OP can edit the html then I would add a class not an id.

Answer (score 0):

Using css you can accomplish this by doing the following:

```
.Dealer:nth-of-type(1){
    padding-left:0px;
}
```

**Edit:**
An explanation, since you seem to be unclear about what is going on. CSS is used for styling of a webpage while the HTML is the structure. The CSS here applies to the first element in the DOM with the `class="Dealer"`. Changing it to be `nth-of-type(2)` would be the second and so on.

Removing the `:nth-of-type(1)` selector would apply that style to **all** the elements on the page where the `class="Dealer"`.

Comment: This seems like it styles all of the images, when OP asked for only the first image to be styled.

Comment: You are correct, updated.

Comment: Not sure why someone's down voted this, it's a valid alternative to the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you may want to give each of the images their own padding, it might help to give the images their own id. Selecting by class as the other answer does sets the padding of all of the images to 0px.

```css
#image1{
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="/img/car1.png" class="Dealer" id = "image1"/>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="/img/car2.png" class="Dealer"/>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="/img/car3.png" class="Dealer"/>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.Dealer { padding-left:5px; } /* guessing a default */
.Container > div:first-child .Dealer {
  padding-left:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="/img/car1.png" class="Dealer"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="/img/car2.png" class="Dealer"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="/img/car3.png" class="Dealer"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML you may add one more css class to the image.

```
<img src="/img/car1.png" class="Dealer dealer-left "/>
```

New CSS

. dealers-left {padding-left :0px ;}

Answer (score 0):

HTML : you may add additional css class to the image

```
<img src="/img/car1.png" class="Dealer dealer-left "/>
```

Css

```
.dealer-left {padding-left :0px;}
```